# Not able to install selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems, installation

My ruby version is 1.9.3

```
ruby -v  returns ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
sudo ruby -v also returns ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
```

But when I try to install selenium webdriver using

```
sudo gem install selenium-webdriver
```

I get the following error :

```
 ERROR:  Error installing selenium-webdriver:
 rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2
```

Please can someone point out where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: Did you try with ruby version : 1.9.2 ??

Comment: OK, it was a problem related to paths and wrong versions installed. Uninstalled rvm , modified the paths and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it was a problem related to paths and wrong versions installed. Uninstalled rvm , modified the paths and it worked fine :)